# Memory leak issue, private data is increasing .Net Framework 4

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, profiling

In the production windows service I had a memory leak in an application.

Service `OnStart` event: This how my service kick off. I suspect it is because of the events. All this service does is, it subscribes couple of events from third party library and execute those events when the events occurred.

In this code `Aggregator` is defined as class property

```
public EventAggregator Aggregator{ get; set;}

Task.Factory
.StartNew(ConnectionManager.AttemptXXXXXXConnection)
                .ContinueWith(task => Aggregator.StartAggregatePublishing(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
                .ContinueWith(task =>
                                  {
                                      if (task.Exception == null) return;
                                      Logger.Log("Failed to start Events aggregation due to:");

                                      foreach (var exception in task.Exception.InnerExceptions)
                                          Logger.Log(exception.Message);

                                  }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted );
```

And the `StartAggregatePublishing` method is defined as follows

```
public IEventHandler<ISystemEvent3> SystemEventHandler
{
   get; set;
}

public IEventHandler<DeviceEvents2EventArgs> DeviceEventHandler
{
     get; set;
}
```

Here `systemEventsManagement` and `deviceEventManagement` belong to third party library events so we can provide our own implementation.

```
public void StartAggregatePublishing()
{
        Logger.Log("Start event publishing");
        XXXData.Events.SystemEvent += SystemEventHandler.HandleEvent;
        XXXdata.Events.DeviceEvent += DeviceEventHandler.HandleEvent;

        systemEventsManagement.Events       += systemEventsManagement_Events;
        deviceEventsManagement.Event        += deviceEventsManagement_Event;
        processor.Start();
        Logger.Log("System and Device events aggregation started.");
}
```

Now the game start here with `EventAggregator`

```
public EventAggregator( int sleepMills = 1000)
{
        processor = new ThreadPausableProcessor( CheckDeviceStates, HandleException, sleepMills );
}
```

and the method which runs for every minute is like this

```
private void CheckDeviceStates()
{
    if ( Device.IsConnected )
    {
            foreach (var deviceState in Skidata.Events.GetAllDeviceStates())
            {
                Logger.Log(string.Format("Checking Handlers for Device id = {0} with Overall state = {1}", deviceState.DeviceId, deviceState.OverallState));

 // Here I am handling pertucular event and logging and reporting stuff.. Nothing major
                DeviceStateHandler.HandleEvent(deviceState);
            }
  // Once I handled all the events I am unhooking all the events and disposing everything.
            Dispose(true);

            int mills;
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
            if ( Int32.TryParse( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PollFrequencyInMills"], out mills ) )
            {
                if ( processor.SleepMills != mills )
                {
                    processor.SleepMills = mills;
                    Logger.Log(string.Format("New polling frequency for DeviceStates processor thread = {0} mills", mills));
                }
            }
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.Log("CheckDeviceStates => Not connected to facility.");
    }
}
```

What I am missing here I don't know I hope I gave enough details.

This is code was written by previous programmer in my place now this code is in production.
Can anyone has any clue where exactly it could potentially go wrong.

I have used DotTrace Memory profiler and had couple of snapshots but I couldn't find the problem everything looks ok to me. I can supply those snapshots if needed.

when service re started Private bytes: 31,383,552

after three days of running Private Bytes: 65,584,648

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Redgate ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) ?
It can visualize the relationship between objects and show most memory-hungry objects

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No I didn't try it.